# Solving $(\cos x-\sin x)\left(2 \tan x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)+2=0$

Tags: trigonometry

Please help me to solve this question

$$(\cos x-\sin x)\left(2 \tan x+\frac{1}{\cos x}\right)+2=0$$

I tried to open the whole LHS expression and the tried to bring it in square format. Something like this
$$\left(\cos x +\frac32\right)^2 - \left(\sin x+\frac12\right)^2-(\sin x-\cos x)^2 =2$$
But after this I am not able to proceed forward.

Comment: A better goal is to factor the left side (the side set to zero). Then one can set the factors each to zero and go on. I don't see right away how to factor, though.

Comment: I tried it but not able to factor it